# How can I rotate FillDraw in Label command?

Tags: asymptote

```
unitsize(1cm);

path  h=(0,4)--(5,3);

transform t=shift(0,-.8);

DefaultHead=SimpleHead;

draw(Label("$\sqrt{2}$",Rotate(dir(h)),align=N,position=Relative(.2)),h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$b$",Rotate(dir(h))),t*h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$c$",EndPoint,red),t^2*h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$d$",Relative(.25),red),t^3*h,align=S,Arrow());
draw(Label("$e$",EndPoint,align=S,red),t^4*h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$f$",position=Relative(.25)),t^5*h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$g$",align=RightSide),t^6*h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$h$",align=Center),t^7*h,Arrow());
draw(Label(s="$im$",Rotate(dir(h)),FillDraw(blue,red)),t^8*h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$j$",Relative(.25)),t^9*h,Arrow());
draw(Label("$k$",Rotate(dir(h)),position=Relative(.75),FillDraw(blue,green)),t^10*h,.5green,Arrow());
//label(rotate(45)*"NE",t^10*h,NE,p2);
shipout(bbox(2mm,white));
```

[image]

A similar question:

For an example:

```
frame f;
label(f,"\textbf{frame - picture}",yellow,Fill(.5blue));
add(rotate(20)*scale(3)*f);
```

[image]

I try

```
unitsize(1cm);
path  h=(0,4)--(5,3);
frame f;
label(f,Label("\textbf{Exemple \`a venir}",Rotate(dir(h))),yellow,Fill(.5blue));
add(Rotate(dir(h))*f);
```

But I was reported as follows:

[image]
How can I rotate this `frame` by **Rotate(dir(`path`))** ?

Comment: Are you looking for an Asymptote version of  the node option `sloped`'s TikZ?

Comment: @BlackMild Certainly I know TikZ can but I need for Asymptote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve the desired output, put the label without rotation into a frame, and then rotate the frame. Rotating the label within the frame and the frame itself will result in a rotated box with the text misaligned.

The mistake you made is that the argument of the `Rotate` function is a transformation, and you gave it a pair. Instead we can just use the `rotate` function, that takes in an angle to rotate by.

```
unitsize(1cm);
path h = (0, 0) -- (3, -1);
real rotate_angle = degrees(dir(h));

frame f;
label(f, "text", yellow, FillDraw(blue, green));

add(rotate(rotate_angle)*f, midpoint(h) + 0.3*dir(rotate_angle - 90));
draw(h);
```

[image: 1]

Comment: So good! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. Charles Staats defined `pathlabel` command (p39, [this tutorial](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote_tutorial.pdf)). I think that `pathlabel`command can be improved a bit to write code more natural (I like to write `"hypotenus"`than `shift(15N)*"hypotenus"`, and write `sloped` than `sloped=true`).

[image: this tutorial]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ 
void pathlabel(picture pic = currentpicture, Label L, path g,
real position=0.5, align align=NoAlign, bool sloped=false,
pen p=currentpen, filltype filltype=NoFill) {
Label L2 = Label(L, align, p, filltype,
position=Relative(position));
if (sloped) {
pair direction = dir(g, reltime(g, position));
real angle = degrees(atan2(direction.y, direction.x));
L2 = rotate(angle)*L2;
}
label(pic, L2, g);
}

unitsize(1cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
pair C=(0,0), A=(4,0), B=(0,3);
label("A",A,SE,blue);
label("B",B,NW,blue);
label("C",C,SW,blue);

draw(A--B--C--cycle);
pen p=magenta;
pathlabel("$b$", C--A, align=S,p);
pathlabel("$a$",C--B, position=.4,align=W,sloped=true,p);
pathlabel(shift(15N)*"hypotenus",B--A, sloped=true,p);
```